# Can't sleep while fasting

Tags: body-fat, sleep, intermittent-fasting

I fast once a week to be healthy and improve performance. It is intermittent fasting (I restrict eating to a four hour window).

I have insomnia almost every time and a quick google search shows multiple forums with the same issue — but no resolution. I almost never have insomnia when I don't fast.

Is it ok to have insomnia, or is something else (eg. hormones out of whack) causing me to have insomnia when I fast?

Comment: From experience, dropping below 1000 calories is not a good thing to do before competition.  Your planning is off if you need to do that.

Comment: try supplements like ZMA or atleast magnesium bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If intermittent fasting gives you insomnia, the way to solve that is to stop intermittent fasting. The lack of sleep will do more damage to your health, performance and overall well-being than the intermittent fasting would help those things. Find some other way of achieving your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind, I found an equivalent post on the cognitive science stackexchange.

https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5537/how-is-fasting-related-to-insomnia

I will try upping the caloric intake and eating more veggies in the 4 hour window on my fast day (and taking magnesium, thanks s3v3ns).